# Using a private OSM file as custom overlay on OSMand?

Tags: gps-tracking, maps, offline-map, osmand

I have a custom OSM file which contains just a boundary of some region, and I would like to have it permanently displayed in my OSMand app, as an overlay or underlay.

I created the file using gpsbabel to convert from a KML file.

I have a hard time figuring out how to make OSMand see the file as available for underlay or overlay. When I click "Configure Map", and then "Overlay map...", Enable, "Install more..." it shows me a long list of maps, but no option to use the OSM file I created.

I know I can display the GPX file on my map using the Show GPX data option in "GPX files" menu, and that works, but just curious to learn if and how I can display custom maps using overlay or underlay.